# Skillsaw 5150 - blade won't turn if blade stud tight but blade won't cut if any looser

Tags: powertools, troubleshooting

Blade won't turn if blade stud tight as I would normally have it.  Any looser though it won't cut and the blade stops once it makes contact with the wood but the motor is still running.  I assume I should be able to spin the blade by hand when the unit is in-plugged but not the case when I tighten the blade stud with the slide wrench. I can spin it when looser. Any thoughts as to what the issue could be?  Thank-you in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that the spacer behind the blade is intact. If it is not then tightening the blade will cause it to bind/rub on the housing of the saw. Also my saw has spacers on both sides of the blade. You could "google" your saw to see what parts may be missing.